# How to configure JMX with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, jmx

I have created a Spring Integration application with Spring Boot.  I would like to know how to configure  JMX with Spring Boot.  I believe by default JMX is configured when using Spring Boot Actuator.

Do I need to configure anything else to be able to export MBeans for Spring Integration?

Most of the example I see have the following line in the applicationContext.xml

```
<context:mbean-export/>
<context:mbean-server/>
```

My Application.java class looks like this.

```
package com.jbhunt.app.consumerappointmentintegration;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml")
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Adding this line to the configuration doesn't seem to export the Spring Integration mbeans

```
@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(server = "mbeanServer",  defaultDomain="my.company.domain")
```

I'm referencing this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TetfR7ULnA8

Answer (score 21):

As you understand the Spring Integration JMX is enabled by default, if you just have `spring-integration-jmx` in the classpath. And, of course, if `spring.jmx.enabled = true` (default).

You can't overrride that just declaring one more `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`, because it is based on `@Import` and you just can't override import classes because of (from `ConfigurationClassParser`):

```
imports.addAll(sourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(Import.class.getName(), "value"));
```

If imported classes are already there, they aren't overridable.

You have several choices to achieve your requirements:

1. Disable default Spring Boot JMX - just addind to the `application.properties` `spring.jmx.enabled = false` and continue to use `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`
2. Configure `IntegrationMBeanExporter` `@Bean` manually.
3. Just configure your `my.company.domain` domain in the `application.properties`:

   ```
   spring.jmx.default_domain = my.company.domain
   ```

Comment: Adding spring-integration-jmx to the classpath did the trick.  Why wouldn't this be include in spring-boot-starter-integration?  Thanks for the help again!!

Comment: Because in most cases people don't want to have JMX in their apps. Of course, it might be a good point to discuss. Feel free to raise an GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues. Mention me, please, there - @artembilan

Comment: Issue has been created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1440

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not planning, but +1 to my answer would be great ;-)

Comment: What exactly is meant by "add spring-integration-jmx to the classpath"? And is that just for a custom jmx mbean server / exporter?

Comment: Sorry, looks like very broad subject, so requires a separate SO thread.

Comment: How to define a dynamic random value to jmx.default-domain in the use case of hosting multiple applications in a single tomcat service?

Answer (score 5):

It is quite late to add this; but in addition to the `endpoints.jmx.domain` I found it useful to change the `spring.jmx.default-domain` to someting unique per application

This is with multiple instances of Spring Boot 1.4.1 apps running in Tomcat 7

Comment: There is a discussion ongoing regarding this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5911 

Hope, Spring devs fixes this